# Spark runtime error for MLlib api using sbt run

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run the following code using sbt package and sbt run. I am getting a runtime error that doesn't make sense to me. The code works great on spark-shell. The error occurs when executing the computeSVD line. If this line is commented out, the program works fine. I have seen similar issues for other API for the MLlib library. It will be great if someone can provide insights into the problem.

Code:

```
package com.sracr.test

import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Matrix
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SingularValueDecomposition
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix

object Test { 


       def main(args: Array[ String ]) {

         val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MySparkApp").setMaster("spark://127.0.0.1:7077")

         var ctx : SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)

         ctx.addJar("target/scala-2.11/spark-test_2.11-1.0.jar")

         println("Hello, This is a start!")

         val data = List(
           Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))),
           Vectors.dense(2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
           Vectors.dense(4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0))

         val dataRDD = ctx.parallelize(data)

         val mat: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(dataRDD)

         println(mat.numCols())

         val svd: SingularValueDecomposition[RowMatrix, Matrix] = mat.computeSVD(2, computeU = true)

         println(mat.numRows())

         println("It Works!!!!!")

         ctx.stop()


       }

}
```

Error:

```
$sbt run
[warn] Executing in batch mode.
[warn]   For better performance, hit [ENTER] to switch to interactive mode, or
[warn]   consider launching sbt without any commands, or explicitly passing 'shell'
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ani.das/Projects/spark/MySpark/spark-test/project
[info] Set current project to spark test (in build file:/Users/ani.das/Projects/spark/MySpark/spark-test/)
[info] Running com.sracr.test.Test 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.0
17/07/06 10:51:18 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/07/06 10:51:18 WARN Utils: Your hostname, 127.0.0.1 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 105.145.28.172 instead (on interface en0)
17/07/06 10:51:18 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ani.das
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ani.das
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/07/06 10:51:18 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ani.das); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(ani.das); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 65196.
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /private/var/folders/4c/s3nt_0s96z57zfxc3dlyq3swjl4fq9/T/blockmgr-5317c7b1-ff8d-463a-8405-dd7c3f12074a
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 408.9 MB
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/07/06 10:51:19 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4041.
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://105.145.28.172:4041
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://127.0.0.1:7077...
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /127.0.0.1:7077 after 31 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20170706105119-0007
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20170706105119-0007/0 on worker-20170706103441-105.145.28.172-64630 (105.145.28.172:64630) with 8 cores
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20170706105119-0007/0 on hostPort 105.145.28.172:64630 with 8 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20170706105119-0007/0 is now RUNNING
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 65198.
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 105.145.28.172:65198
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 105.145.28.172, 65198, None)
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 105.145.28.172:65198 with 408.9 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 105.145.28.172, 65198, None)
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 105.145.28.172, 65198, None)
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 105.145.28.172, 65198, None)
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
17/07/06 10:51:19 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR target/scala-2.11/spark-test_2.11-1.0.jar at spark://105.145.28.172:65196/jars/spark-test_2.11-1.0.jar with timestamp 1499363479936
Hello, This is a start!
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: first at RowMatrix.scala:61
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (first at RowMatrix.scala:61) with 1 output partitions
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (first at RowMatrix.scala:61)
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at test.scala:27), which has no missing parents
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1408.0 B, free 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 958.0 B, free 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 105.145.28.172:65198 (size: 958.0 B, free: 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at test.scala:27)
17/07/06 10:51:20 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
17/07/06 10:51:21 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(null) (105.145.28.172:65200) with ID 0
17/07/06 10:51:21 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6215 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:21 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 105.145.28.172:65202 with 366.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 105.145.28.172, 65202, None)
17/07/06 10:51:21 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 105.145.28.172:65202 (size: 958.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 503 ms on 105.145.28.172 (executor 0) (1/1)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (first at RowMatrix.scala:61) finished in 1.712 s
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: first at RowMatrix.scala:61, took 1.885817 s
5
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122) with 2 output partitions
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 1 (treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122), which has no missing parents
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.6 KB, free 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1560.0 B, free 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 105.145.28.172:65198 (size: 1560.0 B, free: 408.9 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:996
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 2 tasks
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6223 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6258 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 105.145.28.172:65202 (size: 1560.0 B, free: 366.3 MB)
17/07/06 10:51:22 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, 105.145.28.172, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 1]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6258 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6223 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 2]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 5, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6258 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 1.0 (TID 4) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 3]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 6, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6223 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 6) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 4]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6223 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.2 in stage 1.0 (TID 5) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 5]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 8, 105.145.28.172, executor 0, partition 1, PROCESS_LOCAL, 6258 bytes)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 6]
17/07/06 10:51:22 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) on 105.145.28.172, executor 0: java.lang.NullPointerException (null) [duplicate 7]
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 1
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122) failed in 0.391 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 105.145.28.172, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: treeAggregate at RowMatrix.scala:122, took 0.403468 s
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 105.145.28.172, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
[error]     at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] 
[error] Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 105.145.28.172, executor 0): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1981)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1025)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1127)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeGramianMatrix(RowMatrix.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix.computeSVD(RowMatrix.scala:194)
    at com.sracr.test.Test$.main(test.scala:33)
    at com.sracr.test.Test.main(test.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:2028)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
17/07/06 10:51:22 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$1.run(ContextCleaner.scala:67)
17/07/06 10:51:22 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
17/07/06 10:51:22 ERROR Utils: throw uncaught fatal error in thread SparkListenerBus
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1245)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://105.145.28.172:4041
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 5 s, completed Jul 6, 2017 10:51:22 AM
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/4c/s3nt_0s96z57zfxc3dlyq3swjl4fq9/T/spark-4bc93888-b930-4621-9cc8-b44fc3b6bd9e
17/07/06 10:51:22 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/4c/s3nt_0s96z57zfxc3dlyq3swjl4fq9/T/spark-4bc93888-b930-4621-9cc8-b44fc3b6bd9e/userFiles-c5140f8e-6edb-4c89-b113-02d406019feb
```

Comment: This problem was due to a version issue. It is now resolved. I was using MLlib 2.1.0 with Spark 2.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to a version issue. It is now resolved. I was using MLlib 2.1.0 with Spark 2.1.1.